# jQuery Determine if a word is repeated consecutively in a string

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to be able to check to see if a **word** is repeated more than twice in a string. For example:

```
    $string = "Hello hello hello."
```

Is there a way to do this in jQuery? Just to be clear, I **don't** want to check for a specific word or character that's been repeated, I want to check to see if **any** word has been repeated more than twice. I want this to help prevent users from trying to spam my forum. I was thinking that a regex may be the answer but I've no idea what I'm doing when it comes to regex.

Comment: Spammers could just disable javascript if you go with a client-side solution. Isn't it better to add a captcha or something else?

Comment: His use of the syntax `$string` suggests that he might actually do it on the server, since that looks like PHP.

Comment: I'd be careful about this approach, since it's conceivable for words like "to" or "that" to be repeated several times in a sentence and you might throw out some legitimate stuff.  I'm not clear on just what text you're planning to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regexp should do it:

```
/\b(\w+)\b(?:.*\b\1\b){2}/i
```

`\b` matches a word boundary. `\w` matches word constituent characters. Putting `\w+` in parentheses makes it a capture group, in this case group #1. `\1` matches whatever was previously captured. `{2}` after the second group means to match that part twice, so this will look for at least 3 repetitions; replace `2` with whatever minimum you want.

And the `i` modifier makes it case-insensitive, so `Hello` and `hello` will match each other.

You might want to make this only match words of a certain length, for instance 4 or more letters. Then change `\w+` to `\w{4,}`. Otherwise, a sentence that repeats little words like `a` or `the` will trip the filter.

You could also require that the distance between the repetitions should be short, otherwise repeating words far apart in a paragraph might trip it. Change `.*` to `.{,10}` to require that the repeated word be at most 10 characters from the previous one.

Comment: If he wants "more than twice", another `\1` should do it: `/\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b.*\b\1\b/i`

Comment: @ajb Good point. I updated it to use `{n}` to show how to specify an arbitrary minimum number of repetitions.

Comment: I thought the desired match was to be three _consecutive_ words? If so, just change the `.*` to `\s+` and this one does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is really whaqt you need but if you want to identify which words are repeated an easy may be to split the string with space.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var list=$("#wordList").val().split(' ');
  alert ("initial list of words :" + list);
  var listDuplicateWords = list.filter(function(item,i,allItems){
    return i!=allItems.indexOf(item);
  });
  alert ("duplicate words:" + listDuplicateWords);
});
```

see jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/corinnekm/Udg3P/3/